# jquery remove empty or white space values from url parameters

Tags: jquery, regex, parameters

I am using `form.serialize()` to get the list of parameters.

If parameter is empty or its space, i want to remove it from the list.

For example:

```
testAction.action?a=1&b=&c=3
```

should give me

```
testAction.action?a=1&c=3
```

First I was using regex:

```
params = params.replace(/[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g, '');
```

But problem is that if my url is

```
testAction.action?a=1&b=2&c=
```

regex will return me

```
 testAction.action?a=1&b=2& (i have & at the end!)
```

After that I tried jQuery solution

```
$('.myForm').find('input, select').not("[value='']").serialize();
```

but this is only working for empty values -> if i have space parameter in the value that will pass.

Can you help me with some other solution?

Thanks

Comment: You should really handle the empty values at server-side, rather than change the way form data is passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".myForm :input").filter(function () {return $.trim(this.value);}).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
params = params.replace(/&?[^&?]+=(?=(?:&|$))/g, '');
```